# ktor-failing-to-parse-response-no-transformation-found: Trying to parse List<>

Tags: list, kotlin, deserialization, ktor

Am converting a working application from SWIFT to Kotlin to support Android devices and having problems with KTOR deserialization.  Assistance is appreciated!

When trying to deserialize the JSON response into a List<> the below errors out with:

Exception: io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel -> class com.pollensystems.precisionview.MainActivity$Model

Below is the failing code - please advise!

@Serializable
data class SiteResponse(
var SitesID: Int,
var SiteName: String,
var SitePath: String
)

```
private suspend fun loadSites() {
    val text = "Loading Sites..."
    val duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT

    val toast = Toast.makeText(this, text, duration) // in Activity
    toast.show()

    val getsitesforcustomerurl = "https://*****************/GetSitesForCustomer/cmd"

    val client = HttpClient() {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
    }

    val response: HttpResponse = client.post(getsitesforcustomerurl) {
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        setBody(Customer(58))
    }

    if (response.status.value in 200..299) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Successful Response")

        Log.d(TAG, response.bodyAsText())

        try {
            val sites: List<SiteResponse> = response.body()

            if (sites == null)
                Log.d(TAG, "Sites is null")
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Number of sites: " + sites.items.size.toString())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exception: $e")
        }
    }
}
```

}

The response JSON received from response.bodyAsText() prints out to the logs just fine.
[{"SitesID":347,"SiteName":"Avonlea Barley 2022","SitePath":"stoller_avonlea_barley_2022"},{"SitesID":345,"SiteName":"Avonlea Canola 2022","SitePath":"stoller_avonlea_canola_2022"},{"SitesID":344,"SiteName":"Avonlea Lentils 2022","SitePath":"stoller_avonlea_lentils_2022"},{"SitesID":346,"SiteName":"Avonlea Wheat 2022","SitePath":"stoller_avonlea_wheat_2022"},{"SitesID":254,"SiteName":"Chula GA Pecans 2021","SitePath":"stoller_chula"},{"SitesID":354,"SiteName":"Clovis CA Cotton 2022","SitePath":"stoller_clovis_cotton_2022"}]

I am expecting the successful deserialization of the JSON into the sites val and that in this example it will print the size of the sites val as 6.

Have tried Array as well without luck.
val sites: Array = response.body()

---

Confirmed that this is not unique to List<> objects.  Something in my configuration appears to be incorrect.  Similar deserialization fails with a simple json class:

{"UserID":50,"CustomerID":94,"isAdmin":true,"Guid":"658d6b92-fd9a-4290-828e-da1c11c9a217","Expiry":"2023-08-01T00:12:35+00:00"}

@Serializable
data class LoginRequest(val Email: String, val Password: String)

```
@Serializable
data class LoginResponse(
    val UserID: Int,
    val CustomerID: Int,
    val isAdmin: Boolean,
    val Guid: String,
    val Expiry: String
)

fun login(username: String, password: String): Result<LoggedInUser> {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Logging in using userid $username password $password")

        runBlocking {
            val loginurl = "https://********************"

            val client = HttpClient() {
                install(ContentNegotiation) {
                    json()
                }
            }

            val response: HttpResponse = client.post(loginurl) {
                contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                setBody(LoginRequest(username, password))
            }

            if (response.status.value in 200..299) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Successful Response")

                Log.d(TAG, response.bodyAsText())

                try {
                    val lr: LoginResponse = response.body()

                    if (lr == null)
                        Log.d(TAG, "Lr is null")
                    else
                        Log.d(TAG, "Successful Login, Token: " + lr.Guid)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception: $e")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my list of imports:

```
import android.util.Log
import com.pollensystems.precisionview.data.model.LoggedInUser
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.call.body
import io.ktor.client.request.post
import io.ktor.client.request.setBody
import io.ktor.client.statement.HttpResponse
import io.ktor.client.statement.bodyAsText
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.http.contentType
import java.io.IOException
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
try {

val json = kotlinx.serialization.json.Json {
   ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}
                    
val lr : LoginResponse = json.decodeFromString(response.bodyAsText())

if (lr == null)
     Log.d(TAG, "Lr is null")
else
     Log.d(TAG, "Successful Login, Token: " + lr.Guid)
} catch (e: Exception) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Exception: $e")
}
```